# Getting html listitem style value for comparison

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi i have a html list item thats hidden by default on the page that contains a date picker:

```
    <li id="hiddenListItem" style="display:none;">
    <label for="returning">Returning:</label>
    <input type="text" id="returning" required/>
    <span class="form_hint">Proper format "12/04/2014"</span>
</li>
```

If the user selects that they want a return journey then the list item is made visible:

```
 <script>
function needReturn() {
    var item = document.getElementById("hiddenListItem");
    item.style.display = 'list-item';
}</script>


 <script>
function dontNeedReturn() {
    var item = document.getElementById("hiddenListItem");
    item.style.display = 'none';
}</script>
```

If the user click continue button then external .js file validates the form, but if they don't need a return ticket then browser displays message saying please fill in this information.

I was hoping to determine the state of the listitem style and if it was visible then show the warning else continue:

```
        else if (returning === "")
    {
         var item = document.getElementById("hiddenListItem");
         if(item.style.display === "list-item")
         {
            alert("Please enter a return date.");
         }
    }
```

I cant get the above statement to work, any help please.

HTML and JS is not my thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
if (item.style.display !== 'none') {
    alert("Please enter a return date.");
}
```